# How to wrap render Function in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have already wrap the render function in ES5 like:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
  componentDidUpdate:function()
    {
       this.refs.table.cleanSelected();

    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return getItemPropertyData();
    },
   render:ExceptionInterceptor('Test','render',function(){
      return(
       <h1>Test</h1>
       )
    })
});
```

My `ExceptionInterceptor` component look like

```
 var ExceptionInterceptor = function (fileName, functionName, renderFunction, component) {
    return function () {
        try {
            return renderFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
    }
};
```

Now I want to apply same wrapping in ES6 component render method like

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate()
    {
       this.refs.table.cleanSelected();

    }
    getInitialState()
    {
        return getItemPropertyData();
    }
    render()
    {
    return(
      <h1>Test<h1>
     )
    }
}
```

How can I wrap the render method with `ExceptionInterceptor` in my above mentioned es6 code?

Comment: check your `.babelrc` and tell me which preset u use `stage-0`, `stage-1`.... ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI : stage-0

Comment: ok,, you have to migrate to stage-1 or higher ,, and add some plugins.. anyway, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the same guy who gives the solution of decorator, however, it is hard to configure the project to accept decorators ,that's why i will give now a solution which will work ISA , however , it is not elegant as decorator's solution :

Remove `render()` method from `Test`  & Add it  after `Test` class as following  :

```
Test.prototype.render = ExceptionInterceptor('Test','render',function(){
      return(
       <h1>Test</h1>
       )
    });
```

This will not modify `ExceptionInterceptor` , and it makes it compatible with both ES .

The whole file of class will be :

```
 class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super(...arguments);
      this.state = getItemPropertyData();
    }

    componentDidUpdate()
    {
       this.refs.table.cleanSelected();
    }

}

Test.prototype.render = ExceptionInterceptor('Test','render',function(){
      return (
         <h1>Test</h1>
       )
 });

export default Test // export it in the last line (remove export from the beginning of class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Interceptor, the best way to implement it in ES6 is DECORATOR `@ExceptionInterceptor` :  Where you will not need to pass the class name and the method name since it is detected automatically by decorator :

## File : /src/Decorators.js

```
export function ExceptionInterceptor(target, key, descriptor) {

  // console.log(target, key, descriptor) --> try this line if you want to know what decorator detects when it is applied .
   const realFunction = descriptor.value; // which is "render" in your example 

   // Now intercept the realFuntion by overriding `descriptor.value`
   descriptor.value = function() {
    try {
       return realFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }  
  

  };
  return descriptor;
}
```

Then :

## File : /src/Test.jsx

```
import {ExceptionInterceptor} from './Decorators.js'; 

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate()
    {
       this.refs.table.cleanSelected();

    }
    getInitialState()
    {
        return getItemPropertyData();
    }
   
   @ExceptionInterceptor 
    render()
    {
      return (
        <h1>Test<h1>
      )
    }
}
```

---

Check your `.babelrc` config file ; it must contain  :

- `stage-1` or higher as one of persets
- Plugins for decorator transpiling : `transform-decorators-legacy`, `syntax-decorators`

Anyway , i use the following config which is `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3", "react"],
    "env": {},
    "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "react-html-attrs",
        "syntax-decorators",
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
    ]
}
```

Comment: do I need to include ExceptionInterceptor function in each component ?

Comment: Ok i will update the answer by assuming `ExceptionInterceptor ` exist in separated file ... i will notify u when updating done.

Comment: Done ! update includes adding file path for each snippet .. and add `export` to decorator to be able to import it outside (in `Test.jsx` in this example)

Comment: Sorry but one more question how ExceptionInterceptor know about the target, key arguments where we have to pass it ?

Comment: `target, key, descriptor` is given by decorator engine not by YOU.. and it depends on where you apply the decorator (on method , on attr, on class ) .. For your example, we apply the decorator on METHOD (render), thus, the meaning of `target` will be the class of that method... the meaning of `key` will be the method name as string ("render"), the meaning of `descriptor` will be the metedata of the method .. one of metadata is `descriptor.value` which is the method logic itself... i invite your to print `target`,`key`....

Comment: it's not working at my side ExceptionInterceptor  is not even called even if render is successfully render it, if I use descriptor.value then its throw error can read property of undefine so I have tried with descriptor then render is working but the ExceptionInterceptor is not called

Comment: do not worry.. i add another answer which is based on `prototype` object.. and i will keep this answer might be helpful once you migrate to decorators

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134645/discussion-between-abdennour-toumi-and-dhaval-patel).